# How to add functionality of Java implementation which changing existing code?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

Let's say I've an implementation of fund transfer. Now I want to add authentication functionality which should be done before fund transfer (considering we are already receiving username and password in existing request). Which pattern should we use and how we can achieve this without modifying calling class and existing implementation?

What I can think of at this moment is using decorator pattern after extending implementation class, but I believe still we will be required to modify the calling class.

Please find existing Interface and classes.

```
package sb.test.demo.fundtransfer;

public interface FundTransferService {
    public boolean makeTransfer(TransferRequest request) throws Exception;
}

package sb.test.demo.fundtransfer;

public class FundTransferServiceImpl implements FundTransferService {

    @Override
    public boolean makeTransfer(TransferRequest request) throws Exception {
        //Dummy Code
        System.out.println("TransferDone");
        return true;
    }

}

package sb.test.demo.fundtransfer;

public class TestTransfer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TransferRequest request = new TransferRequest();
        request.setSourceAccount(123456);
        request.setDestinationAccount(654321);
        request.setTranserAmount(1000);
        request.setUserName("user1");
        request.setPassword("pass1");

        FundTransferService fts = new FundTransferServiceImpl();
        fts.makeTransfer(request);
    }

}
```

Now, I want want extend FundTransferServiceImpl to createFundTransferServiceNEWImpl which will add authentication.

```
package sb.test.demo.fundtransfer;

public class FundTransferServiceNEWImpl extends FundTransferServiceImpl {
    @Override
    public boolean makeTransfer(TransferRequest request) throws Exception {
        //Dummy Code
        System.out.println("Authenticating..");
        super.makeTransfer(request);
        System.out.println("TransferDone from NEW..");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, without changing TestTransfer.java and FundTransferServiceImpl.java how can I invoke makeTransfer of FundTransferServiceNEWImpl to add authentication? Or, is there any other way to achieve the same?

Please can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want an authenticated client to send private information, you will need to change your existing code to encode the information using keys derived from user ID and password. Other than that, I believe the name of the technique you are looking for is inheritance?

Comment: You need not change the calling class, but just inject a different implementation (if you have coded to interface rather than implementation)

Comment: This sounds like a test/homework question.  With that in mind, I think a decorator/wrapper pattern is what you're after.  If this is production code, then probably "use a library that implements authentication" is the right pattern.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. I have now edited my post and added the interfaces and classes to have a better picture. This is not in production just for my own experiment. Would be happy if anyone can help me here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can make "FundTransferServiceNEWImpl" also implement the interface "FundTransferService" and provide the implementation that you wish in this only, if this was what you asked for!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For this case also I need to modify TestTransfer.java which I can't do (let's say I have some restriction). I was looking for if there is any other way.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, without changing TestTransfer.java and FundTransferServiceImpl.java how can I invoke makeTransfer of FundTransferServiceNEWImpl to add authentication?

You can't without changing the bytecode of either `TestTransfer` (the caller) or `FundTransferServiceImpl` (the callee).

There are two ways to change the bytecode.

You can

- edit the source file and compile
- edit the bytecode before the class is loaded

**Edit the source file**

I would suggest to edit the `TestTransfer` class. The problematic line is

```
FundTransferService fts = new FundTransferServiceImpl();
```

because this line introduces the dependency from `TestTransfer` to `FundTransferServiceImpl`.

I would also suggest to implement the decorator by composition and not inheritence. E.g.

```
public class AuthenticationFundTransferServiceWrapper implements FundTransferService {

    private FundTransferService fundTransferService;

    public AuthenticationFundTransferServiceWrapper(FundTransferService fundTransferService){
        this.fundTransferService = fundTransferService;
    }

    public boolean makeTransfer(TransferRequest request) throws Exception {
        //Dummy Code
        System.out.println("Authenticating..");
        fundTransferService.makeTransfer(request);
        System.out.println("TransferDone from NEW..");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The advantage is that the `AuthenticationFundTransferServiceWrapper` does only depend on the interface `FundTransferService` and not the implementation. This reduces dependencies and makes the class more flexible.

**Editing the byte code**

Editing the bytecode before the class is loaded is possible.

Take a look at

- [AOP](https://docs.jboss.org/aop/1.0/aspect-framework/userguide/en/html/what.html) (aspect oriented programming)
- [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/)
- [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) (bytecode manipulation)
- [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/wiki)

Comment: Thanks for reply. This makes sense. Thanks. +1

Comment: @basu you don't type "+1" you click the up arrow above the answer's score

Comment: I tried that already, but I get some error since I'm new here and have low reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you've identified decorator pattern and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48850170/360211) implemented decorator correctly, but as this is a SOLID principles question I'm going to point out the flaw in that option.

To see the flaw in either inheritance or decorator, consider what happens when the authorization fails. If it throws a new exception type, that is a **Liskov Substitution Principle Violation**. If it changes the behavior by silently not transferring the funds, that is also an LSP violation. If you're going to rely on the boolean returned, you're not going to get a useful failure message back to the user or system admin.

As I see it, there is no way the client code can avoid knowing that the new implementation is checking authorized as it needs to handle either a new exception, or different return values.

Given that, I would recommend you add a new class, like this:

```
public final class TransactionAuthorizationService {

    private final FundTransferService fundTransferService;

    public AuthenticationFundTransferServiceWrapper(FundTransferService fundTransferService){
        this.fundTransferService = fundTransferService;
    }

    public boolean authorizeAndMakeAndTransfer(TransferRequest request) throws Exception {
        //Dummy Code
        System.out.println("Authenticating..");
        fundTransferService.makeTransfer(request);
        System.out.println("TransferDone from NEW..");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Advantages:

- Where before client code dealt with the interface `FundTransferService` you would have no idea until runtime which implementation they had and whether they would be authorizing transactions, now the client code now deals with the `TransactionAuthorizationService` and they call `authorizeAndMakeAndTransfer` so it is very clear.
- As our new class is not implementing an existing interface, there is no Liskov Substitution Violation and is free to return different values or throw different exceptions.

Other tips:

- Stop decorating methods with throw alls: `throws Exception`
- Don't use `InterfaceImpl` as class names, look for what makes them concrete over the abstract interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and inputs.